# Postgis functionalities in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mapping, sql-server-2012, postgis

I'm using Postgresql 8.4, Postgis 1.5 for My GIS works. Planning to change my Database to Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Can we use all the Postgis functionalities in Microsoft SQL Server 2012. Please guide me..

Comment: Straight off the PostGIS homepage: ["PostGIS adds support for geographic objects to the PostgreSQL object-relational database."](http://postgis.org). PostGIS is an extension of PostgreSQL, there's no reason to expect it to work with any other database. There might be something similar for SQL Server but there's no reason to expect them to be compatible.

Comment: Dear mu is too short thank you for the replay.. i'm not trying to compare both database. Actually we have a requirement to change our Postgresql/PostGIS database to SQL Server 2012. And i'm not aware how to do all the routing and postgis functions like setsrid(),st_x(),st_y(),st_shortestline(),st_distance(),st_dwithin(),st_routing_‌​xml_creator() in SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. 
However, Micrsoft SQL-Server > 2005 has geographic objects support integrated.
Most of the functions you mention exist, but they have another name...

And geographic objects are a little more object oriented.

```
SqlGeometry.STX Property
```

Most of the spatial data support resides in Microsoft.SqlServer.Types (.NET assembly), you can decompile it with ILSpy if you want to take a closer look at it.

However, all this object orientation is not really SQL style, so I wonder how fast it is in practise.

Comment: Dear Quandary thank you for your replay. so no way to do in SQL Server 2012 right :(

Comment: @RamRamesh: Well, when you move db systems, you have to move code as well. So it's kind of natural that you will have to re-write the SQL part of your application.

Comment: Dear Quandary.. Yes i have to change all the codes also. Can you provide me the list of equivalent Postgis functions in SQL Server or any examples.

Comment: @RamRamesh: No, I don't have a list anywhere. But you can find everything with http://www.google.com/ncr.